# Dynamic array problems

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Ok my problem is, in my dynamic array function I have an array that gives me the error below.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Revenue
{
};
static int Track_Num_Divisions = 1;
static int Track_Quart_Revenue = 1;
void Program_loop()
{

{

    string D;
    string DN;
    int N;
    double TS;
    double TC;
    double P;

      int arry;
    cout << "how many Revenue tiers do you want?: "; cin >> arry;
    Revenue*  rev = new Revenue[arry];//dynamic array
    for (int i = 0, Track_Num_Divisions = 1;Track_Num_Divisions, i  < arry; i++,Track_Num_Divisions++ )
    {
        Revenue& rev = rev[i];// THIS IS THE ERROR <<<<
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Revenue #"<<Track_Num_Divisions << endl;
        cout << "===========" << endl;
        cout << "<< Ok what is your division name?: " << endl; cin >> D;
        string set_Division_name(D);
        cout << "<< What is your division number?: " << endl;  cin >> DN;
        string set_Division_number(DN);
        while (DN.size() != 4)
        {
            cout << "<< Sorry! Your Division Number cannot exceed or be short of 4. " << endl; cin >> DN;


    }
    delete[] rev;
}
```

Gives this error in function `Dynamic_array
 I think the problem lies in this code>> Revenue& rev =rev[i]`:

> Error  1   error C2676: binary '[' : 'Revenue' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> Error  2   IntelliSense: no operator "[]" matches these operands
>               operand types are: Revenue [ int ]

What should I do?

I am kinda new to this Website still learning the ropes of proper format.

Comment: That's not an MCVE. Far too much useless code. And some background would be appropriate.

Comment: whoa hold the phone it didn't post any of the background info i typed at all. WOW from anyone's point of view this looks bad. Lemme redo this.

Comment: _"Lemme redo this"_ Low chance, the site is very strict now! Improve your original question, to get it fitting the policies. You can't really delete it (since there are upvoted answers now), and it will influence considerations of your account should be _"question banned"_.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem:

```
Revenue& rev = *rev[i];
```

You're dereferencing the value returned by `rev[i]`, but `rev[i]` is not a pointer or a class with an overloaded `operator*`. It's a `Revenue&`.

There's no need for derferencing anything here, just write it as:

```
Revenue& rev = rev[i];
```

Comment: ok now it's telling me there is no operator "[]" matches these operands operand types are Revenue[int]

Comment: @LegacyWink What is the line it's coming from?

Comment: 99 is the line the error is at

Comment: @LegacyWink What is on line 99?